# How to drop a select list by 'onmouseover'?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, selectlist, mouseclick-event

How can I drop down a select list with onmouseover instead of clicking it.
Select list cannot be clicked in javascript to emulate that.
eg: `onmouseover="(this.click())"`

Also setting the 'size of select list' = 'its length' in javascript does not accurately emulate the click event because the adjacent layout changes.
I tried using z-index and position attribute but doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a clever hack from an oldish devshed post

[Select box expand onMouseOver - Dev Shed](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/select-box-expand-onmouseover-532573.html)

here's an example in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/87nyG/1

---

Personally I'd prefer a 3rd party or custom solution as opposed to hacking the `<select>` element

Comment: Thanks though the example you gave works only in some cases. E.g. If you want to display something on the right side of the select element then there will be problems... Hence, will use some 3rd party solution..

Answer (score 1):

It might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent

edit. Nah, it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do what you're asking using a native HTML Select.  You'll have to search out third party options.

Take a look at here for a possibility: http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem. I know it was answered already, but if anyone comes here looking for a more elegant solution, you can do this with jquery:

```
$("#select_id").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('size',13); //My select had months, so 13 was appropriate. obviously you can change this
        $(this).css('position','absolute'); //prevents sibling elements from being pushed down
    },
    function(){
        $(this).attr('size',0); //resets select on mouseout
    }
);
```

This will prevent 'hacking' the `select` tag in the HTML.